# Exchange 2007 question

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

We are going to be doing a migration from Exchange 2003 to 2007 relatively soon. We are in the planning phase.
This post was very helpful in answering a few questions I had-
[Exchange Server 2007 Setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/34773/exchange-server-2007-setup)

But I have another one-
A little background first. We are planning on clustering 2 Mailbox servers using CCR and Windows2008 cluster technology. We will have a 'front end' which is where our Hub Transport and Client Access server will reside. We already have a pair of clustered Ironport boxes which handles our Edge Transport server roll.

I believe I've read enough about the install where I believe it will be fairly painless, but the part that confuses me is this-
At what point do we actually join into my existing 2003 architecture? Before I setup the CCR cluster or afterwards?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't install Exchange 2007 until you have your Windows CCR cluster setup.  However, you can prepare Active Directory beforehand.

Please read this document on TechNet which describes the process for configuring CCR and the mailbox role.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to install your server roles in alphabetical order (as an easy way to remember), so, the CAS/Hub box comes before the Mailbox cluster. Your servers will become part of the existing org when you install them - nothing special you have to do there.